# Sass Breakpoint not working in Mavericks?

Tags: sass, breakpoints, osx-mavericks

After installing Mavericks my Sass stopped compiling with CodeKit. It points me to an error with Breakpoint. I've reinstalled the system and after installing SASS and Compass, the Breakpoint installation keeps giving me this error:

```
    ERROR:  Error installing breakpoint:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h


Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/ffi-1.9.3 for inspection.
```

What can I do?

PS: I also did the gem update --system before installing Compass.

Thanks!

Comment: You can try to downgrade your Ruby to version 1.9

Comment: I'm using 1.8 in my iMac running OSX 10.8.5 and it started having this same issue as well: 

<code>
ERROR:  Error installing breakpoint:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb

mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/ruby.h


Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/ffi-1.9.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/ffi-1.9.3/ext/ffi_c/gem_make.out
</code>

Comment: This worked for me in OSX Mavericks

http://stackoverflow.com/a/22384591/2095051

Answer (score 2):

I had this error, and was able to fix it by running:

`sudo ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future gem install breakpoint`

Though apparently it can also by fixed by running:

`export CFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments;
export CPPFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments;
sudo gem install breakpoint`

Got this from: [clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22703393/clang-error-unknown-argument-mno-fused-madd-wunused-command-line-argumen)