# Installing scrapy failing on cleaning

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, installation, scrapy

I have been trying to get `Scrapy` installed using pip in order to scrape a NBA schedule and scores for the season. Been working on simply trying to get it installed for the last 6 hours. I have followed the set up instructions word for word but still am not able to get it to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated. The terminal window output is below. Thanks so much! Using mac osx btw.

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Scrapy in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Scrapy-0.22.2-py2.7.egg
Downloading/unpacking Twisted>=10.0.0 (from Scrapy)
  Downloading Twisted-13.2.0.tar.bz2 (2.7MB): 2.7MB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/private/var/folders/22/642hcs8n6sx5xg59phv8rw2c0000gn/T/pip_build_andrew/Twisted/setup.py) egg_info for package Twisted

Downloading/unpacking w3lib>=1.2 (from Scrapy)
  Downloading w3lib-1.5.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/private/var/folders/22/642hcs8n6sx5xg59phv8rw2c0000gn/T/pip_build_andrew/w3lib/setup.py) egg_info for package w3lib

Downloading/unpacking queuelib (from Scrapy)
  Downloading queuelib-1.1.1.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/private/var/folders/22/642hcs8n6sx5xg59phv8rw2c0000gn/T/pip_build_andrew/queuelib/setup.py) egg_info for package queuelib

Downloading/unpacking lxml (from Scrapy)
  Downloading lxml-3.3.5.tar.gz (3.5MB): 3.5MB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/private/var/folders/22/642hcs8n6sx5xg59phv8rw2c0000gn/T/pip_build_andrew/lxml/setup.py) egg_info for package lxml
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    Building lxml version 3.3.5.
    Building without Cython.
    Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.28

    warning: no previously-included files found matching '*.py'
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyOpenSSL in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyOpenSSL-0.14-py2.7.egg (from Scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): cssselect>=0.9 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cssselect-0.9.1-py2.7.egg (from Scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six>=1.5.2 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six-1.6.1-py2.7.egg (from Scrapy)
Downloading/unpacking zope.interface>=3.6.0 (from Twisted>=10.0.0->Scrapy)
  Downloading zope.interface-4.1.1.tar.gz (864kB): 864kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/private/var/folders/22/642hcs8n6sx5xg59phv8rw2c0000gn/T/pip_build_andrew/zope.interface/setup.py) egg_info for package zope.interface

    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.dll' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
Downloading/unpacking cryptography>=0.2.1 (from pyOpenSSL->Scrapy)
  Downloading cryptography-0.3.tar.gz (208kB): 208kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/private/var/folders/22/642hcs8n6sx5xg59phv8rw2c0000gn/T/pip_build_andrew/cryptography/setup.py) egg_info for package cryptography
    OS/X: confusion between 'cc' versus 'gcc' (see issue 123)
    will not use '__thread' in the C code
    c/_cffi_backend.c:14:10: fatal error: 'ffi.h' file not found
    #include <ffi.h>
             ^
    1 error generated.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/22/642hcs8n6sx5xg59phv8rw2c0000gn/T/pip_build_andrew/cryptography/setup.py", line 156, in <module>
        "test": PyTest,
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 112, in setup
        _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
      File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 239, in __init__
      File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 264, in fetch_build_eggs
      File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 620, in resolve
      File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 858, in best_match
      File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 870, in obtain
      File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 314, in fetch_build_egg
      File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 593, in easy_install
      File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 623, in install_item
      File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 811, in install_eggs
      File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1017, in build_and_install
      File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1005, in run_setup
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Setup script exited with error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    OS/X: confusion between 'cc' versus 'gcc' (see issue 123)

will not use '__thread' in the C code

c/_cffi_backend.c:14:10: fatal error: 'ffi.h' file not found

#include <ffi.h>

         ^

1 error generated.

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

  File "/private/var/folders/22/642hcs8n6sx5xg59phv8rw2c0000gn/T/pip_build_andrew/cryptography/setup.py", line 156, in <module>

    "test": PyTest,

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 112, in setup

    _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)

  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 239, in __init__

  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 264, in fetch_build_eggs

  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 620, in resolve

  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 858, in best_match

  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 870, in obtain

  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 314, in fetch_build_egg

  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 593, in easy_install

  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 623, in install_item

  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 811, in install_eggs

  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1017, in build_and_install

  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1005, in run_setup

distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Setup script exited with error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/22/642hcs8n6sx5xg59phv8rw2c0000gn/T/pip_build_andrew/cryptography
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/andrew/.pip/pip.log
```

Answer (score 3):

Follow these steps:

First install cryptography:

```
brew install pkg-config libffi
export CFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
export CPPFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/libffi/3.0.13/lib/pkgconfig/
pip install cryptography
```

Then install lxml using:

```
xcode-select --install
```

And then install scrapy using:

```
pip install Scrapy
```

or

```
easy_install Scrapy
```

Sources:

1. [Error installing bcrypt with pip on OS X: can't find ffi.h (libffi is installed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875270/error-installing-bcrypt-with-pip-on-os-x-cant-find-ffi-h-libffi-is-installed)
2. [Cannot install Lxml on Mac os x 10.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19548011/cannot-install-lxml-on-mac-os-x-10-9)
3. http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html#requirements

Answer (score 2):

I was seeing the same issue with installing cryptography.  Installing xcode command line tools solved the issue for me:

$xcode-select --install

$sudo pip install cryptography

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce your problem locally, but my advice would be to uninstall Scrapy, install the dependency (cryptography), and then try installing Scrapy again.

```
pip uninstall scrapy
pip install cryptography
pip install scrapy
```

If that *still* doesn't work for you, try using HomeBrew or MacPorts to install OpenSSL, then [follow these steps](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/#using-your-own-openssl-on-os-x) to tell the cryptography package to use the OpenSSL version already installed on your system.