# Error starting Scrapy project

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

When I am trying to start scrapy, I get this error. Why would it come up?

> $ scrapy startproject tutorial 
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/Applications/anaconda/bin/scrapy", line 5, in  from
>   pkg_resources import load_entry_point   File
>   "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-2.1-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py",
>   line 2697, in    File
>   "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-2.1-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py",
>   line 669, in require   File
>   "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-2.1-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py",
>   line 572, in resolve pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound:
>   cryptography>=0.2.1 $

Comment: Looks like you're missing the cryptography library. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23316102/installing-scrapy-failing-on-cleaning

Answer (score 1):

`Scrapy` [has `pyOpenSSL` package as a dependency](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/requirements.txt#L3), which [requires `cryptography` module to be installed](https://github.com/pyca/pyopenssl/blob/master/setup.py#L37). Either, reinstall scrapy from scratch:

```
pip uninstall Scrapy
pip install Scrapy
```

Or, install `cryptography` module separately:

```
pip install cryptography
```

Comment: I am getting an error: pip can't proceed with requirement 'cryptography>=0.2.1 (from pyOpenSSL->Scrapy)' due to a pre-existing build directory.
 location: /private/var/folders/7h/yd5112hd7xb1srw2ddbyrpj40000gn/T/pip_build_feyzi/cryptography
This is likely due to a previous installation that failed.
pip is being responsible and not assuming it can delete this.
Please delete it and try again.     How do I delete it cryptography?

Comment: @FeyziBagirov `pip uninstall cryptography`?

Comment: Why not restart again all the installation process in a virtualenv (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) to create isolated Python environments and re-check dependencies of the libraries ?

Comment: Getting an error again: Command "/Applications/anaconda/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/var/folders/7h/yd5112hd7xb1srw2ddbyrpj40000gn/T/pip-build-_FXDpz/cffi/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/7h/yd5112hd7xb1srw2ddbyrpj40000gn/T/pip-g1Tgr2-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /var/folders/7h/yd5112hd7xb1srw2ddbyrpj40000gn/T/pip-build-_FXDpz/cffi