# Error installing bcrypt with pip on Cygwin: cant find ffi.h (libffi is installed)

Tags: python, cygwin, pip, bcrypt, libffi

Similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875270/error-installing-bcrypt-with-pip-on-os-x-cant-find-ffi-h-libffi-is-installed), I'm having trouble installing bcrypt under Cygwin, and receiving this error:

```
Downloading/unpacking bcrypt
  Downloading bcrypt-1.0.2.tar.gz (40kB): 40kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_Chris/bcrypt/setup.py) egg_info for package bcrypt
    c/_cffi_backend.c:13:17: fatal error: ffi.h: No such file or directory
     #include <ffi.h>
                     ^
    compilation terminated.
...
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    c/_cffi_backend.c:13:17: fatal error: ffi.h: No such file or directory

 #include <ffi.h>
                 ^

compilation terminated.
```

The `libffi-devel` package is installed, and I've also tried using the `--global-option='-I/lib/libffi-3.0.13/include'` argument to tell `pip` exactly where the `ffi.h` file is on my system.

Comment: I got the same error message while installing python-glanceclient. In my case, I solved it by adding the cygwin package "libffi-devel".

Answer (score 0):

I was able to build/install this implementation from source under Cygwin: https://bitbucket.org/alexandrul/py-bcrypt/overview

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem.

Fixed the problem by:

```
cp /usr/lib/libffi-3.0.13/include/*.h /usr/include
```