# Jasmin installation fails on osx while installing cryptography package

Tags: python, macos, pip

I was trying to install jasmine on mac osx and I got following error for `cryptography` package.

> pip install jasmin==0.5.4-beta

I don't have any idea about this error and not much debugging skills to trace the error from pip log

Can anyone please help me to sort out this issue?

***UPDATED*** I have tried following links solutions but it doesn't work for me

https://gist.github.com/davidalber/6bc5c7c43c530642f79e

[Error installing bcrypt with pip on OS X: can't find ffi.h (libffi is installed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875270/error-installing-bcrypt-with-pip-on-os-x-cant-find-ffi-h-libffi-is-installed)

Here are my random try:

> env DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1j_1/lib ARCHFLAGS="-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future" LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1j_1/lib" CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1j_1/include" pip install cryptography
>
> env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" LDFLAGS="-L//usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1j_1/lib" CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1j_1/include"
>
> env DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/libffi/3.0.13/lib/libffi-3.0.13/lib/ ARCHFLAGS="-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future" LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/Cellar/libffi/3.0.13/lib/libffi-3.0.13/lib" CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/Cellar/libffi/3.0.13/lib/libffi-3.0.13/include" pip install cryptography
>
> env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" LDFLAGS="-L//usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1j_1/lib" CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1j_1/include"

I am keep getting following error.

### UPDATED: Here are the pip log details

```
Installing collected packages: cryptography
  Running setup.py install for cryptography
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/Users/bhushanvaiude/** path to project **/build/cryptography/setup.py", line 337, in <module>
        **keywords_with_side_effects(sys.argv)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 971, in run_command
        cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 109, in ensure_finalized
        self.finalize_options()
      File "/Users/bhushanvaiude/** path to project **/build/cryptography/setup.py", line 115, in finalize_options
        self.distribution.ext_modules = get_ext_modules()
      File "/Users/bhushanvaiude/** path to project **/build/cryptography/setup.py", line 74, in get_ext_modules
        from cryptography.hazmat.bindings.commoncrypto.binding import (
      File "/Users/bhushanvaiude/** path to project **/build/cryptography/src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/commoncrypto/binding.py", line 12, in <module>
        class Binding(object):
      File "/Users/bhushanvaiude/** path to project **/build/cryptography/src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/commoncrypto/binding.py", line 34, in Binding
        "-framework", "Security", "-framework", "CoreFoundation"
      File "/Users/bhushanvaiude/** path to project **/build/cryptography/src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/utils.py", line 97, in build_ffi_for_binding
        extra_link_args=extra_link_args,
      File "/Users/bhushanvaiude/** path to project **/build/cryptography/src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/utils.py", line 105, in build_ffi
        ffi = FFI()
      File "/Users/bhushanvaiude/** path to project **/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cffi/api.py", line 56, in __init__
        import _cffi_backend as backend
    ImportError: dlopen(/Users/bhushanvaiude/** path to project **/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_cffi_backend.so, 2): Symbol not found: _ffi_type_double
      Referenced from: /Users/bhushanvaiude/** path to project **/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_cffi_backend.so
      Expected in: flat namespace
     in /Users/bhushanvaiude/** path to project **/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_cffi_backend.so
    Complete output from command /Users/bhushanvaiude/** path to project **/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/Users/bhushanvaiude/** path to project **/build/cryptography/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/7w/8z_mn3g120n34bv0w780gnd00000gn/T/pip-yAn5r8-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --install-headers /Users/bhushanvaiude/** path to project **/include/site/python2.7:
    running install

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

  File "/Users/bhushanvaiude/** path to project **/build/cryptography/setup.py", line 337, in <module>

    **keywords_with_side_effects(sys.argv)

  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup

    dist.run_commands()

  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands

    self.run_command(cmd)

  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 971, in run_command

    cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()

  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 109, in ensure_finalized

    self.finalize_options()

  File "/Users/bhushanvaiude/** path to project **/build/cryptography/setup.py", line 115, in finalize_options

    self.distribution.ext_modules = get_ext_modules()

  File "/Users/bhushanvaiude/** path to project **/build/cryptography/setup.py", line 74, in get_ext_modules

    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings.commoncrypto.binding import (

  File "/Users/bhushanvaiude/** path to project **/build/cryptography/src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/commoncrypto/binding.py", line 12, in <module>

    class Binding(object):

  File "/Users/bhushanvaiude/** path to project **/build/cryptography/src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/commoncrypto/binding.py", line 34, in Binding

    "-framework", "Security", "-framework", "CoreFoundation"

  File "/Users/bhushanvaiude/** path to project **/build/cryptography/src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/utils.py", line 97, in build_ffi_for_binding

    extra_link_args=extra_link_args,

  File "/Users/bhushanvaiude/** path to project **/build/cryptography/src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/utils.py", line 105, in build_ffi

    ffi = FFI()

  File "/Users/bhushanvaiude/** path to project **/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cffi/api.py", line 56, in __init__

    import _cffi_backend as backend

ImportError: dlopen(/Users/bhushanvaiude/** path to project **/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_cffi_backend.so, 2): Symbol not found: _ffi_type_double

  Referenced from: /Users/bhushanvaiude/** path to project **/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_cffi_backend.so

  Expected in: flat namespace

 in /Users/bhushanvaiude/** path to project **/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_cffi_backend.so

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /Users/bhushanvaiude/** path to project **/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/Users/bhushanvaiude/** path to project **/build/cryptography/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/7w/8z_mn3g120n34bv0w780gnd00000gn/T/pip-yAn5r8-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --install-headers /Users/bhushanvaiude/** path to project **/include/site/python2.7 failed with error code 1 in /Users/bhushanvaiude/** path to project **/build/cryptography
Storing complete log in /Users/bhushanvaiude/.pip/pip.log
```

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22073516/failed-to-install-python-cryptography-package-with-pip-and-setup-py

Comment: thanks, I got that too and actually I am trying to install all dependancies as mentioned in that post. But I was not sure that this is the solution to my question so posted it here. If that help me I will delete my question

Comment: @limelights please check I have added more info. Please let me know, if you get any idea about what I have done wrong

Comment: Do you have libffi-dev installed ?