# pip cffi package installation failed on osx

Tags: python, macos, pip, python-cffi

I am installing cffi package for cryptography and Jasmin installation.

I did some research before posting question, so I found following option but which is seems not working:

### System

> Mac OSx 10.9.5
>
> python2.7

### Error

```
c/_cffi_backend.c:13:10: fatal error: 'ffi.h' file not found

#include <ffi.h>

         ^

1 warning and 1 error generated.
```

Please guide me on following issue.

Thanks

### Command

> env DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/ ARCHFLAGS="-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future" LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib" CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include" sudo -E pip install cffi

### LOG

```
bhushanvaiude$ env DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/ ARCHFLAGS="-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future" LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib" CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include" sudo -E pip install cffi
Password:
Downloading/unpacking cffi
  Downloading cffi-0.8.6.tar.gz (196kB): 196kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package cffi
    warning: unknown warning option '-Werror=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future'; did you mean '-Werror=unused-command-line-argument'? [-Wunknown-warning-option]
    1 warning generated.
    
Downloading/unpacking pycparser (from cffi)
  Downloading pycparser-2.10.tar.gz (206kB): 206kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package pycparser
    
Installing collected packages: cffi, pycparser
  Running setup.py install for cffi
    warning: unknown warning option '-Werror=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future'; did you mean '-Werror=unused-command-line-argument'? [-Wunknown-warning-option]
    1 warning generated.
    building '_cffi_backend' extension
    cc -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -Qunused-arguments -pipe -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future -DUSE__THREAD -I@@HOMEBREW_CELLAR@@/libffi/3.0.13/lib/libffi-3.0.13/include -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c c/_cffi_backend.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/c/_cffi_backend.o
    warning: unknown warning option '-Werror=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future'; did you mean '-Werror=unused-command-line-argument'? [-Wunknown-warning-option]
    c/_cffi_backend.c:13:10: fatal error: 'ffi.h' file not found
    #include <ffi.h>
             ^
    1 warning and 1 error generated.
    error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command /Users/****project path***/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/Users/****project path***/build/cffi/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/7w/8z_mn3g120n34bv0w780gnd00000gn/T/pip-e6d6Ay-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --install-headers /Users/****project path***/include/site/python2.7:
    warning: unknown warning option '-Werror=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future'; did you mean '-Werror=unused-command-line-argument'? [-Wunknown-warning-option]

1 warning generated.

running install

running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/cffi

copying cffi/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/cffi

copying cffi/api.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/cffi

copying cffi/backend_ctypes.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/cffi

copying cffi/commontypes.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/cffi

copying cffi/cparser.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/cffi

copying cffi/ffiplatform.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/cffi

copying cffi/gc_weakref.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/cffi

copying cffi/lock.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/cffi

copying cffi/model.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/cffi

copying cffi/vengine_cpy.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/cffi

copying cffi/vengine_gen.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/cffi

copying cffi/verifier.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/cffi

running build_ext

building '_cffi_backend' extension

creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/c

cc -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -Qunused-arguments -pipe -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future -DUSE__THREAD -I@@HOMEBREW_CELLAR@@/libffi/3.0.13/lib/libffi-3.0.13/include -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c c/_cffi_backend.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/c/_cffi_backend.o

warning: unknown warning option '-Werror=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future'; did you mean '-Werror=unused-command-line-argument'? [-Wunknown-warning-option]

c/_cffi_backend.c:13:10: fatal error: 'ffi.h' file not found

#include <ffi.h>

         ^

1 warning and 1 error generated.

error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error installing bcrypt with pip on OS X: cant find ffi.h (libffi is installed)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875270/error-installing-bcrypt-with-pip-on-os-x-cant-find-ffi-h-libffi-is-installed)

Comment: get the same error, tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875270/error-installing-bcrypt-with-pip-on-os-x-cant-find-ffi-h-libffi-is-installed -> didn't work for me.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In your terminal try and run:

```
xcode-select --install
```

After that try installing the package again.

By default, XCode installs itself as the IDE and does not set up the environment for the use by command line tools; for example, the `/usr/include` folder will be missing.

Running the above command will install the tools necessary to run compilation from the command line and create the required symbolic links. Since Python packages compile native code parts using the command-line interface of XCode, this step is required to install Python packages that include native components.

You only need to do this once per XCode install/upgrade, or if you see a similar error.

Comment: can you explain this more?

Comment: It appears this sets up the command line tools for development with Xcode.  This is a good tip.

Comment: Worked for me... Not sure why this is a requirement though :)

Comment: Notably this happens to me with every OS X upgrade too.  Perhaps Xcode updates often require one to be on the latest version of OS X.

Comment: This doesn't work for me on macOS 12.2.1. It says `xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates`, after which cffi installation keeps failing

Answer (score 25):

Install CLI development toolchain with

```
$ xcode-select --install
```

If you have a broken pkg-config, unlink it with following command as mentioned in comments.

```
$ brew unlink pkg-config
```

Install libffi package

```
$ brew install pkg-config libffi
```

and then install cffi

```
$ pip install cffi
```

Source: [Error installing bcrypt with pip on OS X: can't find ffi.h (libffi is installed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875270/error-installing-bcrypt-with-pip-on-os-x-cant-find-ffi-h-libffi-is-installed)

Comment: You deserve salute my friend !

Comment: I first had to "brew unlink pkg-config" and then following your instructions it works great.

Comment: `brew install pkg-config libffi` then `pip install cffi` was all I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score -3):

Running the below command in terminal took care of my issue.

xcode-select --install