# cffi installation got failure on MacOs 12.5 with pip

Tags: python, gcc

I am trying to install "cffi" with pip on MacOs 12.5 but I got an error 
python : 3.8.10
pip : 22.2.2 
Apple clang version 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2.5)

Command :

`pip install cffi`

Error

```
  /opt/homebrew/bin/gcc-11 -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libffi/include -DFFI_BUILDING=1 -DUSE__THREAD -DHAVE_SYNC_SYNCHRONIZE -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libffi/3.4.2/include -I/Users/faraz/.pyenv/versions/3.8.10/include/python3.8 -c c/_cffi_backend.c -o build/temp.macosx-12.5-arm64-3.8/c/_cffi_backend.o -iwithsysroot/usr/include/ffi
  gcc-11: error: unrecognized command-line option '-iwithsysroot/usr/include/ffi'
  error: command '/opt/homebrew/bin/gcc-11' failed with exit status 1
```

I also did some tips which mentioned in the following link but it didn't work for me.
[pip cffi package installation failed on osx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27740044/pip-cffi-package-installation-failed-on-osx)

Comment: Warm welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. I assume your question does not fit to SO. Please [ask the cffi folks](https://groups.google.com/g/python-cffi).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading `cffi` documents, I find out that,`"/opt/homebrew/bin/gcc-11"` is gcc, and not clang and `cffi` doesn't explicitly support gcc on MacOS.
So, I added the following lines to `~/.bash_profile` and it worked

```
# Set Clang as the default compiler for the system 
export CC=clang 
export CFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments 
export CPPFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
```