# Is it possible to use Cocoa API with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, cocoa

I was wondering if it is possible to use Cocoa (Apple's API) with Python, so being able to run any code like in this [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace), so NSWorkspace functions and so on, this might be a super stupid question, but I was still wondering if it was possible...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

There are Python packages, kind of wrappers around Objective-C, install them like:

```
$ pip install pyobjc-core
$ pip pyobjc-framework-Cocoa
$ pip pyobjc-framework-Quartz
```

https://pypi.org/project/pyobjc-framework-Cocoa/

Comment: If you wouldn’t mind, could you show how to execute a function like NSWorkspace.shared.openFile() with pyobjc?

Comment: I retrieve [the list of running apps](https://github.com/ipaleka/arrangeit/blob/master/arrangeit/darwin/collector.py) with `NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().runningApplications()` after NSWorkspace is inported with `from AppKit import NSWorkspace`. Try with similar approach, I'm not near an OS X right now to check.

Comment: Can't seem to be able to install AppKit... Or at least python can't find the module even though I did as you did, and installed all the things you told me to install...

Comment: Dunno, I've managed to install it and use it, chek this [Travis-CI log](https://travis-ci.org/ipaleka/arrangeit/jobs/569815918) from line 91-102. That installation went fine and all the tests passed.

Comment: @ipaleka - out of curiosity, is PyObjC installed with Xcode? I have it on my system — at least, I can access objc elements through python — but I don't recall ever installing it manually.

Comment: Really don't know that, probably, or maybe with custom Python install.

Comment: I still don't understand how to get AppKit to work, I can't figure out how to install the module...

Comment: Just that it can't find the module itself, so Im guessing Im somehow not installing it correctly...

Comment: You should install cairo, try with `pip install pycairo` or check [this](https://scoobygalletas.blogspot.com/2011/08/installing-cairo-and-pycairo-in-mac-os.html).

Comment: On the install command and build command for ./waf it gives an error. This is the [output](https://psty.io/r?q=fd15)

Comment: That's from install from source, what errors you've got with pip install (`pip install pycairo`)?

Comment: Just read the errors. In this case you need `libffi`. After googling, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25854749/11703358) came up.

Comment: You should try with Python3 then. https://arrangeit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/development.html#mac-os-x

Comment: This seems like it is way too complicated, is there no easier method?

Comment: As you can see from that Travis-Ci log, for Python3 it's simple as `pip pyobjc-framework-Cocoa`. I suppose you have problems because of Python 2.

Answer (score 1):

MacOS by default comes with python 2.7 and pyObjC 2.5, and has done for years. If you want a newer version of either python, such as python 3, or the newest version of pyObjC, then you have to install it yourself.

The latest version of [pyObjC is 5.2](https://pypi.org/project/pyobjc/).

However, on a default installation of MacOS from at least Snow Leopard onward, the following should work:

```
python
   >>> import Appkit
   >>> AppKit.NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().runningApplications()
```

Catalina is stated to be the last version to contain python bundled.