# Can't Install Several Python Packages

Tags: python, package, twisted, pip, easy-install

I have easy_install and pip installed on my system. I have tried installing a number of different packages such as Twisted and Scrapy and keep getting following error message:

```
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_vagrant/cryptography
```

I am running OS X 10.9 and have tried it on my local machine as well as an Ubuntu virtual machine in vagrant. Regardless of what I do I keep getting some variation of the above error. Oddly enough, I can install some packages like Flask, Django and few others.

I have tried this using virtualenv and to no avail.

Here is one example of an error:

```
Command /Users/meblumen/Desktop/Virtual_Environments/scraper/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/Users/user1/Desktop/Virtual_Environments/scraper/build/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/bs/lkq_06gs33s1s_56zywwds2w0000gn/T/pip-Wk9wD5-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/user1/Desktop/Virtual_Environments/scraper/include/site/python2.7 failed with error code 1 in /Users/user1/Desktop/Virtual_Environments/scraper/build/lxml
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/user1/.pip/pip.log
```

That was after trying to install lxml by using `pip install lxml`. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide more information: complete error messages, what versions of things you have installed, the exact sequence of commands you've entered, your environment, and particularly, how you installed pip and easy_install.

Comment: I am running Python 2.7. I installed pip on my OS X install via easy_install. In Ubuntu it was installed using setuptools. From a command perspective all I was entering was: 

pip install [package name]

whereby [package name] was something like: twisted or scrapy

I also tried:

easy_install scrapy

Comment: You still haven't properly described the failure.  Try including a complete transcript of your install attempt in the question.

Comment: For example, when you say "via easy_install", what was the exact easy_install command line you used?  Did you install a new version of easy_install first or did you use the system one?

Comment: @Glyph, to answer your question, I believe I used the system version. I tried doing an installation using virtualenv and in a Vagrant ubuntu virtual machine. I updated my post to include the entirity of 1 error message I received. One thing I am wondering that might have caused the problem is I installed Anaconda a week or so ago to try out some of the scikit-learn, panda etc... packages. Could it have something to do with my PATH? Sorry for all the dumb questions but I am very new to this and clearly quite confused.

Comment: This stuff can get very confusing.  The best thing that you can do to get started is to un-install Anaconda.  It frequently causes problems like this, especially on Macs.  Second, do you notice how that error message ends with telling you to inspect `~/.pip/pip.log`?  Perhaps the contents of that file are interesting :).  (You will need to re-produce the error and then copy it right away; `pip.log` gets over-written each time `pip` runs.)

Comment: @Glyph, thanks for all your help. It appears that this might be the issue:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22703393/clang-error-unknown-argument-mno-fused-madd-wunused-command-line-argumen

The thing that solved it was this but I don't understand what is actually taking place:

ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future pip install <your package>